# Using member access operator (.) to initialize char array in stractures

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, char

I am java developer and I try to learn c++. Right now I am learning structers.
I saw an example of using structers in the internet (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_structures.htm).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Books {
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
};

int main( ) {
    struct Books Book1;        // Declare Book1 of type Book
    struct Books Book2;        // Declare Book2 of type Book

   // book 1 specification
   strcpy( Book1.title, "Learn C++ Programming");
   strcpy( Book1.author, "Chand Miyan"); 
   strcpy( Book1.subject, "C++ Programming");
   Book1.book_id = 6495407;
   ...


   return 0;
}
```

This code is working but I have one question: Why the compiler doesn't allow using the line `Book1.title = "Learn C++ Programming";` but he does allow using the line `strcpy( Book1.title, "Learn C++ Programming");`. Why do `Book1.title = "Learn C++ Programming";` different then `Book1.book_id = 6495407;` (exept the type, of curse)?

Comment: The very short version is that this is legacy behavior inherited from C, which doesn't really _have_ strings, and that if you use `std::string title;` etc, instead of `char title[50];` etc, it'll work more like the way you want.  The long answer requires an entire C++ textbook.

Comment: This situation is easier to visualize if you consider your members `title`, `author` and `subject` to be sets of 50 and 100 `char` instead of thinking of them as single string objects. You *could* do the same thing as `book_id` but you would need to assign each `char`. `Book1.title[0] = 'L'; Book1.title[1] = 'e';` etc. `strcpy` is a function designed to avoid having to do that (in addition to only copying relevant characters). Using `std::string` will allow you to use your members as proper string objects and assign to them directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `std::string` instead of char arrays. Unless there is some specific reason you need to use arrays, there is a lot more functionality in the `std::string` type.